# Processing Optional Value from Mono in Project Reactor

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I want to have a `Mono` that calls another async method that returns an `Optional` type to:

1. have a value if the `Optional` is not empty,
2. is `MonoEmpty` if the `Optional` value is empty.

Here's what I do right now:

`Mono.fromCallable(() -> someApi.asyncCall())
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get)`

Obviously, this is not ideal since it uses two operators after the callable completed. If possible, I'd like to have the `Mono.empty()` or mono value from inside `fromCallable`.

What is the best way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is an alternative with `flatMap` that's a bit better than `Optional.isPresent` and `Optional.get` that can lead to accidentally calling get on empty `Optional`:

```
Mono.fromCallable(() -> someApi.asyncCall())
  .flatMap(optional -> optional.map(Mono::just).orElseGet(Mono::empty))
```

Comment: How about `Mono.fromCallable(() -> someApi.asyncCall()).flatMap(Mono::justOrEmpty)`

Answer (score 14):

Mono have `justOrEmpty` method that you can use with `Optional<? extends T>` type. When `Optional.empty() == true` we would have `MonoEmpty`.

> Create a new Mono that emits the specified item if Optional.isPresent() otherwise only emits onComplete.

```
Mono<String> value = Mono.justOrEmpty(someApi.asyncCall());
```

Comment: The problem here is you make the call `someApi.asyncCall()` immediately. accepted answer is better solution.

Comment: I checked the source!! `someApi.asyncCall()` is invoked immediately. not lazy. The expectation is - mono should not execute anything unless someone subscribes

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
Optional<Integer> optional = Optional.of(5);
Mono<Optional<Integer>> monoWithOptional = Mono.just(optional);
Mono<Integer> monoWithoutOptional = monoWithOptional.flatMap(Mono::justOrEmpty);
```